# How do I use rvest to extract the digits of pi from the following website?

Tags: html, r, rvest

I am trying to extract the digits of pi from a website using the rvest package in R, but it keeps giving me an `xml error`.

```
library(rvest)
pisite <- read_html("http://www.eveandersson.com/pi/digits/1000000")
pitable <- pisite %>% 
html_node(xpath = "/html/body/table[2]/tbody/tr/td[1]/pre/text()[1]")
```

I keep getting the result:

> {xml_missing}
>   NA

Note that I copied the value used for the xpath from the chrome website inspection tool. Although it does look a bit different to the xpaths I have gotten before.

Not sure what to change. Guessing it is something really simple. Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe this could help:

```
library(rvest)
library(dplyr)
# here the site
pisite <- read_html("http://www.eveandersson.com/pi/digits/1000000")

# here you catch what you need
pi <- pisite %>% html_nodes("pre") %>% html_text()

# here you replace de \n with nothing, to have the numbers only
pi <-gsub("\n", "", pi)

pi
[1] "3.1415926535897932384626433832795028841971   ...and so on..."
```